# TextView in ListView not being set from CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have an app that retrieves data from a webservice in the form of an array. In the getView() of the adapter i set the TextViews to the elements in the array. The array is called recordItem and has various elements one of which is "status". Status is a String that can be either completed, ncr, or waiting. if i set the TextView in the listview directly with the value completed, ncr or waiting there's no problem.

I don't want to display the full string in the textview but rather display a C, NCR or W instead. I have a series of "if statements" that check the array element and then sets the textview to the respective character.

The problem is that no character is being displayed. why?

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent,
                    false);

            TextView startTime = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
            TextView duration = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
            TextView status = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
            TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);

            String record = list.get(position).toString();
            String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
            Log.e(TAG, "itemin record = " + itemsInRecord.length);
            String[] recordItem = new String[itemsInRecord.length];

            for (int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++) {

                recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];
                Log.e(TAG, "x = " + x);
            }

            String withoutBraket = recordItem[0].substring(11);
            String withoutSecs = withoutBraket.substring(0, 6);

            Log.e(TAG, "recordItem = " + recordItem[2]);


            if(recordItem[2].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")){

                statusField = "c";

            }else if(recordItem[2].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("NCR")){

                statusField = "NCR";

            }else if(recordItem[2].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Waiting")){

                statusField = "W";
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "statusField = " + statusField);

            startTime.setText(withoutSecs );
            duration.setText( recordItem[1]);
            status.setText( statusField);
            name.setText( recordItem[3] + recordItem[4]);
            callID = recordItem[5];
            needName = recordItem[6];

            return rowView;

        }
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowstarttime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowduration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowstatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowclientname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Pasha Hi updated the post with xml

Comment: Ok, this line: Log.e(TAG, "statusField = " + statusField);
return correct status?

Comment: @Pasha no it's returning null. recordItem[2] however returns the correct value

Comment: @Pasha it's ok solved it. recordItem[2] needed trim() calling on it. There must have been white space in it. thanks anyway.

Comment: As I understood You right, list contains rows, but each text field in row is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recordItem[2] needed trim() calling on it. .equals not picking the strings up because of this.